# Очередь в C++. Если хочу создать очередь на N элементов, заполняется только на N-1. Почему так?

Tags: c++, очередь

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class queue {
    private:
        int* arr;
        int head, tail;
        int N;
    public:
        queue () { 
            head = 0;
            tail = 0;
            N = 10;
            arr = new int[N];
        }
        queue (int N) { 
            this->N = N;
            head = 0;
            tail = 0;
            arr = new int[N];
        }
        bool checkOverflow() {
            if (head == (tail + 1) % N) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        bool checkEmpty() {
            if (head == tail) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        void insert(int element) {
            if (checkOverflow() == true) cout << endl << endl << "QUEUE IS OVERFLOWED" << endl;
            else {
                arr[tail] = element;
                tail = (tail + 1) % N;
            }
        }
        void extract() {
            if (checkEmpty() == true) cout << endl << endl << "QUEUE IS EMPTY" << endl;
            else {
                cout << arr[head];
                head = (head + 1) % N;
            }
        }

};

int main() {
    bool answer = true;
    int element, N;
    cout << "Enter the amount of queue: ";
    cin >> N;
    queue one(N);
    do {
        cout << endl << "Enter 1 if you want to add an element;" << endl << "enter 0 if you want to extract an element" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == true) {
            cout << endl << "Enter the element of queue: ";
            cin >> element;
            one.insert(element);
        } else {
            cout << endl << "Extracted element: ";
            one.extract();
        }
    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: просто для заметки. не пишите `if () return true else false` пишите сразу `return ()` Не пишите `if ( ... == true)` часть с `==true` можно убрать

Comment: а если серьёзно, то вы сами подумайте. Tail это указатель записи. Он показывает ЗА последним элементом. а вы считаете очередь переполненной если он указывает НА первый элемент. Таким образом в  N - 1 элемент нельзя сделать запись. Установить N = 1 и посмотрите на ваши функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В замкнутой очереди признак переполнения памяти с помощью двух индексов даёт неопределённое состояние. Пустая очередь имеет индексы :

```
head = 0 
tail = 0
```

, а заполненная такие-же :

```
head = 0 
tail = ( 0 + N ) % N = 0
```

и переменная `tail` с доступными значениями `0 .. N-1` имеет всего N состояний. А фактически этих состояний должно быть N+1 : `0 .. N`.

Можно убрать переменную `tail` и вместо неё хранить `size` - количество элементов. Тогда функция `insert` может выглядить так :

```
void insert(int element) {
  if ( size == N )
    cout << endl << endl << "QUEUE IS OVERFLOWED" << endl;
  else {
    arr [ ( head + size ) % N ] = element ;
    ++ size ;
  }
}
```